# How to binarize an image using the triangle method?

Tags: image-processing, histogram, thresholding, c#

I'm a college student taking an image processing class. My homework is to apply the "triangle method" on a grayscale image and binarize the image using the result. The problem is that I think I have an incorrect understanding of what this "triangle method" is. Information about this algorithm is scarce and I couldn't find any sources that answer my misunderstandings.

This is my understanding of this algorithm:

[image: Triangle method]

1. Take the source image and create its corresponding histogram;
2. Normalize the histogram;
3. Find the highest (MAX) and the lowest (MIN) values of the histogram. If the lowest value is found more than once, we take the one furthest away from the highest value;
4. Draw an imaginary line between MAX and MIN. This will form a right triangle with the axes;
5. Normalize the triangle so that the X-axis edge and the Y-axis edge are both = 1;
6. Take each histogram value (h[i]) from within the triangle and calculate the distance between h[i] and the segment created by MIN and MAX;
7. Find the longest distance between h[i] and the MIN-MAX segment. Take the "i", add an offset (in the picture, it's THR) to it (de-normalize the offset before adding it). This should be the desired threshold that can later be used to binarize the image.

This approach didn't work as intended for me. For example, this is my input image:
[image: Coins]

What I assume should happen is for the result image to look like a black canvas with white circles on it. The results that my algorithm yields are not even close to that.

This is the histogram of the image (from https://www.sisik.eu/histo):

[image: Histogram]

In the context of my algorithm, the MIN value is found for i=1 and the MAX value is found for i=17. Thus, the returned binarization threshold (w/o the offset) is somewhere around 12. This gives (upon binarization with the resulted threshold) me a mostly white picture with black spots, which is far from intended.

My code for this problem (C#) (Maybe it helps with clarifying my thought process?)

```
public static double[] GrayHistogram(Image<Gray, byte> grayImage)
        {
            double[] histogram = new double[256];

            for (int y = 0; y < grayImage.Size.Height; ++y)
                for (int x = 0; x < grayImage.Size.Width; ++x)
                    histogram[grayImage.Data[y, x, 0]] += 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
                histogram[i] /= grayImage.Size.Height * grayImage.Size.Width;

            return histogram;
        }

        private static double PointToLineDistance(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
        {
            double numerator = System.Math.Abs(((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y0)) - ((x1 - x0) * (y2 - y1)));
            double denominator = System.Math.Sqrt(System.Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2) + System.Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2));
            return numerator / denominator;
        }

        public static int TriangleMethod(Image<Gray, byte> grayImage, double offset)
        {
            double[] histogram = GrayHistogram(grayImage);
            double histogramMax = -0.1, histogramMin = 1.1;
            int histogramMaxPos = 0, histogramMinPos = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (histogram[i] > histogramMax)
                {
                    histogramMax = histogram[i];
                    histogramMaxPos = i;
                }
                if (histogram[i] < histogramMin)
                {
                    histogramMin = histogram[i];
                    histogramMinPos = i;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; ++i)
                if (histogram[i] == histogramMin && System.Math.Abs(i - histogramMaxPos) > System.Math.Abs(histogramMinPos - histogramMaxPos))
                    histogramMinPos = i;

            double xMax, yMax, xMin, yMin, xCrt, yCrt, distMax = -1;
            int result = 0;
            yMax = 1;
            yMin = 0;

            if (histogramMaxPos < histogramMinPos)
            {
                xMax = 0;
                xMin = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                xMax = 1;
                xMin = 0;
            }

            for (int i = System.Math.Min(histogramMaxPos, histogramMinPos) + 1; i < System.Math.Max(histogramMaxPos, histogramMinPos); ++i)
            {
                double num1 = i - System.Math.Min(histogramMaxPos, histogramMinPos);
                double num2 = System.Math.Abs(histogramMaxPos - histogramMinPos);

                xCrt = num1 / num2;
                yCrt = histogram[i];
                double distance = PointToLineDistance(xCrt, yCrt, xMax, yMax, xMin, yMin);
                if (distance > distMax)
                {
                    distMax = distance;
                    result = i;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, sorry for the long post and for my English.

Comment: Your MIN point should be the last bin in the histogram that is not zero. The point is on the axis itself, the actual value of that bin is irrelevant. Or at least that is how am implemented it. The algorithm is not very sensitive to the exact location of this point, but you do want it to be on the end of the longer tail of the main peak (not at the shorter end, where you picked it).

Comment: That solved it, thanks! :)